# Web content scraping to find out if a website offers digital music

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I have a form which collects details about user's small business. One of the fields is the website of the small business. Once the form is submitted I perform content scraping of the website to see if the website has any objectionable content.

One of the validation that should be done is to verify if the website offers digital music - like to check if a website allows users to purchase MP3 or movies etc. How do I do this? I am using beautiful soup library to parse contents of a page. How do I check if the page offers digital music for sale?

In general, how can I scrape a page and find it the website offers a shopping cart at all?

Comment: thats to big. Like you can try some stuff but in general its to complicated. You can never be sure if the result is correct. On default you could check if the site has the word/suffix "mp3" somewhere or if there is a "shopping cart ". Search for classes or icons. "Add to cart" is a common keyword but as I said that is not accurate and you can never be sure if the output is correct

Comment: Right now I am checking to see if there are any of the list of phrases like - add to cart, buy now, download now, add to basket etc. but I am not sure if this is a comprehensive list.

Comment: Isn't there a solution for this at all?